# How does Entity Framework know that X entity has a collection of Y entity when using Lazy loading?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this class

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

Below code is from the designer class generated by the EF migrations

```
    modelBuilder.Entity("XYZ.Models.Entities.Product", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("XYZ.Models.Entities.Teacher")
                    .WithMany("Courses")
                    .HasForeignKey("TeacherId");
            });
```

I've checked my database, there is no such thing that shows where the Products IDs stored or anything, yet it works!

Where does that info get stored?

Comment: what do you mean by *where the product ids are stored*? They are stored in the db.

Comment: I've checked the db and there is no such a thing?

Comment: You mean the database is not there at all?

Comment: No, here's the teacher table, (http://oi67.tinypic.com/174f35.jpg) as you see, there is no info regarding the list of products which is a property in the entity Teacher.. I hope I've explained clearly.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong database. Add some data to the table and see if it ends up im the Teacher table

Comment: You should be looking at the `Product` (or `Course`) table though. There will be a column called `TeacherId` which is FK (foreign key) to `Teacher` table PK (primary key) `Id` column. The "collection" is a logical representation of the join between the two tables, or in other words, `Teacher.Courses` == `Courses.Where(course.TeacherId == Teacher.Id)` (pseudo-code). Makes sense?

Comment: @IvanStoev, Yes! I didn't know that when I do that It'll change the Courses table! Thank you. can you make this comment to be considered as an answer ? Because it is the answer! have a good day.